# preload and cache data in a Web API OWIN application

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm building a Web API application using OWIN and hosting in IIS. I now want to preload some data from a database which can be used in the controller methods without loading the data from the database for each request. I have also followed this [guide](http://blog.devdave.com/2015/05/setting-up-web-api-2-with-windsor-using.html) to setup Windsor as IoC container. Does anyone know how to properly set this up?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do.  In the Startup class, populate one or more classes with the database data.  Do this as you would normally load data into a data store.

Register each of these classes with your IoC from the Startup class.  It is best to separate the controller from data layer, so create a business logic layer or a repository layer that takes your data store class in the constructor like this:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IDataStore _dataStore;

    public Service(IDataStore dataStore)
    {
        _dataStore = dataStore;
    }
}
```

Register the service with your IoC and you should be good to go.

Hope that helps.